# How to use NODE_ENV to choose which database is connected?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I am attempting to use the value for NODE_ENV in my node.js server to connect to a different database when running my tests. How can I get the correct values for NODE_ENV i.e 'development', 'test', 'production' to make what I've got below work?

```
import pg from "pg";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();
const Pool = pg.Pool;

const enviroment = () => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "test") {
    return process.env.TEST_DATABASE;
  } else {
    return process.env.DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE;
  }
};

const pool = new Pool({
  password: process.env.PASSWORD,
  host: process.env.HOST,
  port: process.env.PORT,
  database: enviroment()
});

export default pool;
```

.env includes

```
NODE_ENV=development
NODE_ENV=production
NODE_ENV=test
```

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with this code? Does it not work? If so, what's in your `.env` file and what does `process.env.NODE_ENV` equal to?

Comment: @KelvinSchoofs currently my .env folder includes the variables ive just added to the main question.

Comment: Why do you have `NODE_ENV` triple? And you don't have `TEST_DATABASE`, `DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE`, `PASSWORD`, ... defined? _(not that you should show your actual values of course_

Comment: yeah, everything else is working and defined. When it comes to the NODE_ENV triple Im not sure - I'm aware that is not right. Am I supposed to have something related to NODE_ENV in my .env?

Comment: Rolled back so the comments and answer(s) make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your code is **fine**. I think you made a typo in your `.env` file.

Here is a sample for your `.env`:

```
NODE_ENV=test
TEST_DATABASE=mongodb://localhost:27017
DEVELOPMENT_DATABASE=mongodb://localhost:27018
PASSWORD=abcxyz
HOST=localhost
PORT=8000
```

**Don't use `NODE_ENV="test"`, spaces, or anything like this.**